# How to set localized selected language to the session inside controller?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, bootstrap-4, laravel-5

```
 <div class="dropdown" >
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle btn-local"  type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Select Language
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu localization-dropdown" id="country-list">
        @foreach(LaravelLocalization::getSupportedLocales() as $localeCode => $properties)
            <li>
                <a rel="alternate" id="ln" class="black" hreflang="{{ $localeCode }}" href="{{ LaravelLocalization::getLocalizedURL($localeCode, null, [], true)}}">
                    {{ $properties['native'] }}
                </a>
            </li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
```

Hi all as I am using this get to get the selected localized language and set it to the url and it's working fine, but I want to get that language and send it to the controller to set un session for further operation based on that so here I don't know how to achieve this I tried ajax but that didn't work for me, any help would be appreciated thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use some middleware to do this. It would look at the route and then set the session, before the controller gets to it. This way it’ll work on all of your routes.

This is unfortunately too large for a Stack Overflow response, but it’s not a simple drop-in piece of code. The [documentation explains how to create middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware), you can then update the session in the middleware.

Comment: Middleware is already there but I don't know where to write the code for session ,this localization part is done by using middleware only and its changing the url , on language selected

Comment: You’ll need two. The one that’s already there just redirects the user if they haven’t got a language. You know their language, so that middleware doesn’t need to do anything. You need to write a new middleware, perhaps called it `SetNewLanguageMiddleware`. That’s where your code should go.

Comment: Hi Thomas thanks, can you please provide some link for the same keeping my requirement in mind.